# Swift Push Notification

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, push-notification, weather

I want to be able to use push notification, but not to fetch data off the server. Instead I want it to act as an update method for my weather app, so that new data is fetched even when the app is closed. Is it possible to fake a push notification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add following code to your **Info.plist** file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

And in the JSON payload of the remote push add the following flag

```
content-available: 1
```

so it looks like this:

```
aps: { 
(…)
content-available: 1,
(…)
}
```

The push notification with this flag will be silent (user will not see the notification) and iOS will give your app about 30 seconds to download new content/update itself. It is designed just for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can send notification who are not displayed to the user, if they do not contains any text. These are not "fake" notifications, but notifications.

But the application will receive them only when it will be launch (and if the user allowed notification).
The other issue is that payload size is limited in notification, so you can not do a full update of your app with it.

The usual scenario is that notification is used to inform the client that he needs to update, and eventually give a 'summary' of what's new in order to provides rapid feedback to the user.

Comment: Ok but how would I then update the data while the app is closed?

Comment: You can't. But why would you do this? Your app is closed, and the user can not see it. The only moment where your app needs to have updated information, it's when it's open.

Comment: I have a today widget and Apple watch set up with the app. So I want it to update hourly.